# How to tell in the script that if the scp failed, try wget

Tags: linux

I have this script :

```
cd /tmp/
scp user@8.8.4.1:/onboot/OTA.sh /tmp -i /usr/script/id 2> /dev/null
if
chmod 775 /tmp/OTA.sh
/tmp/OTA.sh &
sleep 30
rm -rf /tmp/OTA.sh

fi
```

I want to tell in the script that if the `scp` failed, try `wget`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$? contains exit code of last called command. You can simply check if its non-zero:

```
scp user@8.8.4.1:/onboot/OTA.sh /tmp -i /usr/script/id 2> /dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    #wget here
fi
```

Comment: thanks guys for responding ,@scony
i tried that but its give me back  line 28: [[1: not found

Comment: thanks a lot guys  i found a way around it, i had to put the "then" after ]; thanks alot..regards

Answer (score 1):

`man scp`

```
EXIT STATUS
     The scp utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.
```

The exit status can be accessed using the variable `$?` in bash.